# Delay in few seconds apache response

Tags: php, apache, centos

I was have this issue since new centos 7 server and about a month im googling about it with no luck.

My problem was apache send response in delay about 4sec after php script was execute.

Im using xdebug to see any long script/function have delay but not.

below example my xdebug trace file.

```
TRACE START [2019-06-10 08:58:27]
0.0080     295160     -> define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing') /var/www/html/index.php:64
0.0097     295160      >=> TRUE
0.0097     295160     -> define('HAVE_EMAIL', FALSE) /var/www/html/index.php:68
0.0097     295160      >=> TRUE
0.0098     295160     -> ini_set('display_errors', 0) /var/www/html/index.php:86
0.0098     295576      >=> '1'
.
.
.
1.1370    7960056         -> log_message($level = 'debug', $message = 'Total execution time: 1.1056') /var/www/html/system/core/Output.php:532
1.1370    7960104           -> write_log($level = 'debug', $msg = 'Total execution time: 1.1056') /var/www/html/system/Common.php:478
1.1370    7960152             -> strtoupper('debug') /var/www/html/system/core/Log.php:168
1.1370    7960184              >=> 'DEBUG'
1.1370    7960152            >=> FALSE
1.1370    7960104          >=> NULL
1.1370    7959800        >=> NULL
1.1370    7959800       -> Hooks->call_hook($which = 'post_system') /var/www/html/system/core.php:543
1.1370    7959848        >=> FALSE
1.1370    7959752      >=> 1
1.1371    7901032     -> xdebug_stop_trace() /var/www/html/index.php:298
1.1371    7901080
TRACE END   [2019-06-10 08:58:28]
```

from the trace above we can see the script start at 0.0080secs and done at 1.1371secs. it took about 1.1secs to complete the script.

but in my apache access file log was capture:

```
[06/11/2019:10:32:13 +0800] XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 16972 -ms- 5298889
```

and clearly apache send response after 5298889 ms (5.298secs).

where 5.2 minus 1.1 = 4.1sec and i need to find out what happening to this extra 4++secs.

here some firebug crop image the waterfall timeline which also show 5.3 second total time.
[image]
[image]

**PHP: version 5.6,
Apache: 2.4.6,
OS: Centos 7,
Firewall: disable,
SElinux: disable**

**Apache Error Log: no luck and /var/log/message: no luck**

did anyone have idea what is going on? and any help would be appreciate.

thanks.

Edit:

Another finding, i try open and close browser. first request after browser open was fast and then it consistently took 5secs. :(

```
<here im close and open again browser>

[06/11/2019:15:00:15 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 449531
[06/11/2019:15:00:44 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5261276
[06/11/2019:15:12:27 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5210857
[06/11/2019:15:20:33 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5324744
[06/11/2019:15:22:23 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5193830
[06/11/2019:15:24:15 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5298699
[06/11/2019:15:31:05 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5484622



<here im close and open again browser>

[06/11/2019:15:31:35 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 333542
[06/11/2019:15:31:56 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5195283
[06/11/2019:15:32:03 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5275482
[06/11/2019:15:32:11 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 12218 -ms- 5664277
[06/11/2019:15:33:47 +0800] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx TLSv1.2 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 "GET report/stat/sh1 HTTP/1.1" 16269 -ms- 5224315
```

Comment: looks like the network, not the server, the 'extra'  time is between the server and the client

Comment: maybe because TTFB was no delay for receiving first byte and start delay after download the contents.

Comment: Could be the DNS resolution time. You can consider using any of the caching mechanism to improve this time.

Answer (score 0):

Àfter few days struggling find out, now it clearly my memcached touch function took the extra time. It hurt when xdebug never capture the delay and now im working to fix.it.. Anyway thank for all of you willing to help.